# Simple AS2 problem

Tags: actionscript-2

I have: (1)

```
this["btn_a"].onRelease = function (){
    this._parent[up_mc]._visible = true;
    this._parent[add_mc].num = random(10)+190;
    trace(this._parent);
}
```

and I change it to (2)

```
function click1(){
    this._parent[up_mc]._visible = true;
    this._parent[add_mc].num = random(10)+190;
    trace(this._parent);
}
this["btn_a"].onRelease = function (){
    click1();
}
```

When I click the button in (1), it shows '_level9', but when I click the button in (2), it shows 'undefined'. I know nothing about AS2, so please help me and explain in details. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scoping....

in the first one, you are calling a function that belongs to the button.
in the second, you are declaring a function at a level  (your case:level9) and then calling it where it sits.

I think.

```
this["btn_a"].onRelease = function (){
    trace(this._parent+" "+this); // traces: _level0 _level0.btn_a
}

function click1(){
    trace(this._parent+" "+this); // traces: undefined _level0
}
this["btn_b"].onRelease = function (){
    click1();
}
```